# How to fix "Couldn't assign value into ICollection property"

Tags: c#

I have a relationship between Login(parent) and Member(child) table. 
After generate the model, I'm not able to assign the value into the child table.

> Model:

```
public partial class tbl_Login
{
    public tbl_Login()
    {
        tbl_MemberDetail = new HashSet<tbl_MemberDetail>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }        
    public string login_username { get; set; }
    public string login_password { get; set; }         

    [InverseProperty("Login_")]
    public virtual ICollection<tbl_MemberDetail> tbl_MemberDetail { get; set; }
}


public partial class tbl_MemberDetail
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Age{ get; set; } 
    public string DOB{ get; set; }
}

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> createUser(tbl_Login account)
    {
        account.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        account.login_username = "user01";
        account.login_password = "123456";
        account.tbl_MemberDetail.
    }
```

The problem is, why I'm not able to assign the value into account.tblmemberdetail? Please help! Thanks!

[Problem 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yovAb.jpg)

This is my expected result:

```html
{
  "id": "EB94F819-1E35-447C-A6B1-14EDE4FC68BA",
  "login_username": "testuser11",
  "login_password": "123456",  
  "tbl_MemberInfo": {
    "id": "BD748329-79C0-4863-9860-DD2C70EE3750",
    "Name": "Andy",
    "Age": "30",
    "DOB": "2019 June 30"
  }
}
```

Hi, I had retried, and it seems okay already. Is this the correct?

```html
var lstMemberDetail = new tbl_MemberDetail { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "test", Age = "test", DOB ="test" }; 
tbl_Login account = new tbl_Login(); 
account.Id = Guid.NewGuid(); 
account.login_username = "user01"; 
account.login_password = "123456"; 
account.tbl_MemberInfo.Add(lstMemberInfo);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not able to assign"? You have `.Add` where you can add a new item to your collection.

Comment: Hi, I had retried, and it seems okay already. Is this the correct?

var lstMemberDetail = new tbl_MemberDetail { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "test", Age = "test", DOB ="test" };

            tbl_Login account = new tbl_Login();
            account.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            account.login_username = "user01";
            account.login_password = "123456";
            account.tbl_MemberInfo.Add(lstMemberInfo);